# Usage of JWK in a JWS

Tags: json, haskell, jwt

I'm trying to learn about JWT. I've read [several](https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec) [blog](https://medium.com/ag-grid/a-plain-english-introduction-to-json-web-tokens-jwt-what-it-is-and-what-it-isnt-8076ca679843) [post](https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3) and a github [repo](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-json-web-tokens) and I think I've understood it quite well.

There's this [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/jose-jwt-0.8.0) in Haskell that deals with JWT and its kind. In this library, using JWK is mandatory, while most of the library I used in another language doesn't. I'm puzzled of what JWK is, seems it is hardly mentioned in the blog post I've read so far.

A quick search yields a result that what I think about JWK is, I don't know if it's right, is basically a JSON object that can be used as a `secret`
 and specifying what algorithm is supported. Can someone clarify that this is true or no. More explanation about it will be gratefully accepted!

Comment: I believe the JWK is simply the key used for signing and/or verifying the JWT. Thus, using it should be mandatory in all libraries unless they support the "none" algorithm (which should never be accepted in production anyway, or maybe ever?). So, I believe that using a JWK should be mandatory in most libraries although some might not call it a JWK but simply call it "the key".

Comment: Hi @dvaergiller thanks for your response! I don't think it's just a `secret` since actually there is an ietf [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517) about it. But I'm puzzled about: What is the use case of it? When to use it?

Comment: JWK is a format to describe a public key. This can than be downloaded as part of a JWKS through a public URL. The Public Keys in the JWKS can then be used to validate a signature, e.g. the signature of the JWT. In your situation your JWT should normally have a header entry kid (key id). this kid then corresponds to an entry in a JWKS which contains the information on how to validate the signature of the JWT.

Comment: @autumn322 no it is not a `secret`, but a key. Note that JWT supports signing and encoding using either shared secret or public key. If you want to use shared secret rather than public key signing, I think you should look at the functions `hmacEncode` and `hmacDecode`

Comment: @dvaergiller Oh so JWK serves the same reason for those public/private key that usually takes form of a `.pem` file? Now I feel silly. So when do you want to use those JWK over the `.pem` file? This is the last one I promise!

Comment: @autumn322 I honestly do not know when to use jwkEncode and when to use rsaEncode. But I would love to hear an answer to this one so I'm following this thread =P